# How to save HQ book cover images on Amazon

Tags: amazon, images

[Amazon.com](http://amazon.com) shows the book covers in high quality but I couldn't manage to save those images in my computer. Is there a way to save those images in high resolution?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page with a high-quality image?

Comment: For example: http://www.amazon.com/Doing-Both-Captures-Todays-Tomorrows/dp/0137083645/ref=pd_ts_zgc_b_books_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&pf_rd_p=475709271&pf_rd_s=right-3&pf_rd_t=101&pf_rd_i=283155&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1X4NDAY7VMVKGMZ456D3#reader_0137083645

Comment: How high is "high quality"?

Comment: When you zoom in to the maximum available level for that cover, it's the highest quality for that image.

Comment: I think none of the method in here still work! Can you update please? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found it here: [Abusing Amazon images](http://aaugh.com/imageabuse.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [FireBug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (a bookmarklet).
2. Open up the cover of the page you want to view in Amazon.
3. Press the bookmarklet.
4. Press **Inspect** (top left of the bookmarklet)
5. Press on the image.
6. Underneath the highlighted line, you will see an `img` with a source attribute that starts with `//sitb-images.amazon.com/`
7. Navigate to the `http://` version of this url (e.g. `http://sitb-images.amazon.com/...`).

Comment: Does this method still work? :) I think firefox also have the inspect option. So can I use firefox for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.  I found an easy way using Firefox 25.0.1 (newest version).

It is a bit of a pain though.

1. navigate to an amazon page.

Example:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Camille-Womens-Ladies-Briefs-Three/dp/B00B1EW4YE/ref=pd_sim_sbs_ap_1

Select the picture you want.
Hover your mouse of the small picture.  The large image will rollover on the right.

1. Right click.  Select save page as.
2. navigate to that fold firefox made.
3. sort the folder by dimensions.
4. open up or move the jpg image that is the largest.  usually about 1000x1000

if you have any other ides i would love to hear.

Comment: Does this method work yet? I was not able to use it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps to get an image at least 500px tall or wide.

1. Right click on the image and choose "Copy image URL" (or your browser's equivalent).
2. Open a new tab and past the URL into the address bar.
3. Now delete all characters in between the first `.` of the file name and the `jpg` at the end.

**For example**, this is the starting image url.
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41W0QwAkn2L._BO2,304,203,200_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-click,TopRight,60,-76_AA300_SH20_OU01_.jpg

This is the larger version of the image.
http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41W0QwAkn2L.jpg

Here's a Jing Screencast: http://screencast.com/t/NTBlOTc5YTc

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a way to save images in highest possible resolution. Your solution works for saving for midsize images, but not for the largest available image. There should be a trick for that. (When you zoom in to the maximum available level for that cover, it's the highest resolution for that image.)

Comment: Yup. 500px isn't that high of a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I grab the images out of Temporary Internet Files, the caveman way.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the link for a larger image, then right-click on the cover and then pick "View Image" (for Firefox). Then right-click the image and then save it.

Comment: -1. I know how to normally save images on the web. This won't work on Amazon.

Comment: This worked for me.